# UITextField keyboard return button title

Tags: swift, ios8, uitextfield

I wanted to change the name of the return button key as I'm not developing the app in English. I'm having an `UIAlertController` and added a textField (`.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in <someCode> }`). How can I now change the title of the return button key in *Swift*? Actually there shouldn't be any difference to a normal `UITextField`. Thank for any help :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set custom text for the return key on iOS. There are a number of [options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType) but those are the only ones.

If you are only worried about translation, the keys will be translated automatically depending on the language that is configured on the users device. Otherwise, you are going to have to create an entirely custom keyboard (which is almost certainly not worth the effort).

Comment: Ok, how can I do that then? I used ReturnKeyStyle `.Done` -> I would expect a Done button but the return key name is still 'return'

Comment: @OliverBorchert, you should be setting the `returnKeyType` on your text field **before** the user taps on it.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I'm aware of that - I just recognized it didn't work due to an incredibly stupid mistake. Thank you anyway :]